# Should REST services respond using the input content type?

Tags: web-services, rest

If using JSON, we return JSON. If using XML, we return XML. Would it be acceptable to return form-encoded data for requests where we accept form-encoded data ("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")?

Also, in the case of errors, what do most implementations do? I see many different variations on the theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning form-encoded data, while not a terrible approach, is something I've never seen in the wild. Best, I think, to stick to more common formats. Most APIs choose a default format to send (usually XML or JSON) when none is specified by the request.

As for errors, the main principle of REST is using the methods HTTP already supplies, so firstly return the appropriate error status code (in the [400s and 500s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error)) along with an error message in the response body.

There's no standard format for the body of an error response—it could be as simple as:

```json
{ "error" : "Invalid articled ID" }
```

..or more involved, like [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.rest.html)'s:

```json
{ "stat"    : "fail",
  "code"    : "97",
  "message" : "Missing signature"
}
```

..and its [XML](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.json.html) equivalent:

```json
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rsp stat="fail">
  <err code="97" msg="Missing signature" />
</rsp>
```

Obviously developers using your API will appreciate more verbose error messages. Mainly I think you should seek consistency in your API—if you have a parameter named `Message` in one place don't have one named `message` in another place.

As an aside, I've dealt with an actual third-party production API that not only made the above *faux pas* but returned results as pipe (`|`) separated data enclosed in XML. Literal pipes in values were escaped by another pipe (`||`). I'll leave the further complications we discovered up to your imagination. The moral, anyway, is to use structures and techniques that developers are already used to, and more than that *be consistent* in the choices you make.

Comment: Cool. It felt wrong to send form-encoded data back, hence the question. For clarification: If we support form-encoded data in the request, does it make sense to return JSON or XML in the response?

Comment: It makes sense to me, as long as it's documented.

Comment: Sounds great to me! We want to build around JSON, but legacy callers will still want support for form-encoded POST. With this advice, we can meet the needs. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no reason to.

But a client *can* request a specific format with the Accept: header. If the server doesn't support the format, it should return 406 Not Acceptable. The server can just pick a default if there's no Accept: header at all, or the client used * as a fallback.